# Java deletes my file and creates a new one

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am trying to finish a bank accounts homework assignment. I have a text file, "BankAccounts.txt" which is created if there is no file with that name. However, if the file exists, I do not create it. But Java desides to delete all my code inside of it :(. Can you help me identify why this happens? Thanks <3

Code:

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static File file;
static PrintWriter Vonnegut; //a great writer
static FileReader Max;
static BufferedReader Maxwell;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize();
}

static void initialize(){
    try { // creating banking file
        file = new File("src/BankAccounts.txt");
        if(!file.isFile()) {file.createNewFile();} //if it doesn't exist, create it
        Vonnegut = new PrintWriter("src/BankAccounts.txt","UTF-8");
        Max = new FileReader("src/BankAccounts.txt");
        Maxwell = new BufferedReader(Max);
        //get list of usernames and passwords for later
        usernames = new String[countLines() / 5];
        passwords = new String[usernames.length];
        checkingAccounts = new String[usernames.length];
        savingsAccounts = new String[usernames.length];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this method keeps returning 0... regardless of whether or not my file has data in it.

```
static int countLines() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader Kerouac = new BufferedReader(Max);

    int lines = 0;

    while(Kerouac.readLine() != null)
        lines++;

    Kerouac.close();
    System.out.println(lines);
    return lines;
}
```

After I run the program, unless I call a method that writes to the file, all the contents of the file will be gone.

Comment: why do you need `Vonnegut = new PrintWriter("src/BankAccounts.txt","UTF-8");` ?

Comment: You never write in your file, never close most of your readers/writers.

Comment: Not only do you not close your files, I don't see where you even write any data out.  Did I miss it?

Comment: It's somewhat tricky to open a file for update or append.  If you just blindly open a file for write any prior contents will be lost.  This is the way file I/O works in any language.

Comment: I didn't add my code for writing into the file because it works, I check the file after my program runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!file.isFile()) {file.createNewFile();} //if it doesn't exist, create it
```

Redundant. Remove.

```
    Vonnegut = new PrintWriter("src/BankAccounts.txt","UTF-8");
```

This always creates a new file, which is why the previous line is redundant. If you want to append to the file when it already exists:

```
    Vonnegut = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("src/BankAccounts.txt", true),"UTF-8");
```

The `true` parameter tells the `FileOutputStream` to append to the file.

See the Javadoc.

Or use a `FileWriter` instead of a `FileOutputStream,` same principle.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `PrintWriter` it will always delete the file if it already exists, from the javadoc:

> ...  If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size ...

(i. e. its content will be deleted)

Instead of using `FileReader` and `PrintWriter` you need to use a `RandomAccessFile` to write and/or read your file in this way:

```
RandomAccessFile myFile = new RandomAccessFile("/path/to/my/file", "rw");
```

In this way the file is automatically created if it doesn't exist, and if it does, it just opens it.

Comment: How do I enter a new line using RAF?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant something like this: `raf.seek(fileLength); far.writeChars("\nContentOfNewLine");` (or `far.writeChars(String.format("%s%n", line));` if you want '\n' for Linux or '\r\n' for Windows)

Comment: He doesn't 'need to use RandomAccessFile'. There are several other solutions.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I'm pretty sure you can also open a stream file for append.